# How to read "Contact Name" from inbox messages

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I'm reading sms messages from inbox using content provider. See following code:

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null, null, null, SORT_ORDER);
```

Inside loop I'm fetching all required columns:

```
String body= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
String person = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person"));
```

I'm getting all values properly but **person's name** is returning 'null' value. Please guide me why contact name is not being returned from above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `person` column's value, if it exists, is not the sender's name. It's an ID that you would use to query the Contacts Provider to get the name. If you're getting null for `person`, then you'll have to use the `address`, which is the phone number, to query against. For example:

```
String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

final String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

String displayName = null;
Cursor contactCursor = null;

try {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                                   Uri.encode(address));

    contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                               projection,
                                               null,
                                               null,
                                               null);

    if (contactCursor != null && contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName = contactCursor.getString(
                contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if(contactCursor != null) {
        contactCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now able to get contact names using your code. But it's taking too long to retrieve all messages in Inbox as "displayName" is to be searched against each message. Isn't there a better solution.

Comment: I think the code can be optimized if I use a Hashmap or something to store "Display Name" against "Contact #" after first search and later use it to retrieve without proceeding to given code.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed the part about looping over the whole inbox. And a Map is just what I would suggest. Sounds like you've got it figured out. Lemme know if you need assistance with that.

Comment: Thank you very much bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        uriSms,
        new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I have used this but it isn't giving contact name.